# Draw the relation custom class in class diagram

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I am using Astah I have `get_map_data` method in the `Database` class which has `MapData` as custom class as below. How can I draw the relation to the Database class in the class diagram?

**Database class:**

```
public List<MapData> get_map_data(ArrayList<Integer> selected) {

    List<MapData> LRLDHistory = new ArrayList<>();      
    return LRLDHistory;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't tried Astah, but surely it has a way to add an association with association ends.

Comment: @JimL. The relation you see on the diagram is not an association but an ownership relation. It indicates that Database is owned by MapData (as in "nested under" or "inner class"). I guess the relation is wrong because it seems a bit strange that a Database would be owned by something like MapData.

Comment: Yes, I recognized the containment. I would have used an association.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Dependency towards MapData from Database.
In Astah, you can create Dependency from the button below (in red circle).

[image]